# Outlook not expanding M365 Groups

Tags: azure, outlook, dynamic, microsoft-dfo365

Good morning Folks. I am having some issues and I am going to try and explain this to the best of my ability.

I am reorganizing our Azure environment and part of that is converting mail enabled security groups to dynamic M365 groups. There is about 1600 groups. My PowerShell script to do this has been created and is working as expected. I have not made these changes to all 1600 groups my D-DAY is the 22nd.

This brings me to my issue. When I created my test groups, I noticed that when I pull up the new group in the "To" field in outlook (pulled from the GAL, not using the autocomplete) I noticed that when I hover over the new group email in the "To" field I get a pop up saying there are no members in that group. I checked in Azure and o365 and I have all my 10 users in there, pulled in using my dynamic rule syntax. I do not know why it is showing no members. Being able to see who is in those groups will be well used by our users and something like this will generate a whole bunch of support calls\tickets.

When I try to expand the group, I get an error saying "Cannot perform the requested operation. The command selected in not valid for this recipient. The operation failed"

If anyone has any ideas I would love to hear them.

Thank you Johan

Comment: Open a support case from your tenant. Office 365 support is free. They'll help you solve this without your needing to spend untold amounts of time struggling with it.

Answer (score 0):

I see some disussion about the similar issue as yours:

[Outlook Error Message: Cannot perform the required operation. The command selected is not valid for this recipient. there was an error while expanding the list. The list was not fully expanded](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5a700042-d67d-4c71-a4f8-69ca925eb49c/outlook-error-message-cannot-perform-the-required-operation-the-command-selected-is-not-valid-for?forum=outlook)

*I found another workaround to try. Open a new message, select To:, change address book from "offline address book" to "distribution list", select the list giving errors and press ok so it updates into the To: line
Try expanding
Delete entry and retype distribution list to verify functionality
Expand*

And this one:
[Distribution List problem - Outlook 2016](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1633313-distribution-list-problem-outlook-2016)

*When I've seen this error in the past it's been due to a corrupted autocomplete entry. Open a new email and begin typing the group name until you see it suggested in the drop-down. Then click the X to delete the autocomplete entry. Then either finish typing the group name and hit Check Names to link it, or add it in from the address book by clicking on the To button. You'll now be able to send the email.*